# Rigid manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, tangent-bundle

**Definition** *A compact complex manifold M is called **rigid** if $H^1(M,\Theta_M) = 0$*

$\Theta_M$ is the sheaf of holomorphic sections of the complex tangent bundle.

Let's consider a proper map $f : M \rightarrow B$ whose differential is everywhere surjective. Let's suppose $B$ is connected and choose a point $b \in B$, set $M_b = f^{-1}(b)$. My question is:

If $M$ is rigid then $H^1(M_b, \Theta_{M_b}) = 0$ for every choice of $b \in B$?

I guess my claim is true but I don't find a way to prove it. I thought I could use some exact sequence of sheaves and then the induced long exact sequence but I didn't succeed in applying this idea.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I see no reason for this to be true, though my pool of examples is to small to provide you with a situation where this fails. You should look around for rigid fibered surfaces (where the fibres have genus > 0). I'd be quite surprised if they didn't exist.